# Python Basemap script runs with Anaconda cmd prompt but not with VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, matplotlib-basemap

I'm running an example script for python basemap. Here is the script:

```
import sys
print("Running on = ", sys.executable)
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# setup lambert azimuthal equal area basemap.
# lat_ts is latitude of true scale.
# lon_0,lat_0 is central point.
m = Basemap(width=12000000,height=8000000,
            resolution='l',projection='laea',\
            lat_ts=50,lat_0=50,lon_0=-107.)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='coral',lake_color='aqua')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81.,20.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,20.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua') 
# draw tissot's indicatrix to show distortion.
ax = plt.gca()
for y in np.linspace(m.ymax/20,19*m.ymax/20,9):
    for x in np.linspace(m.xmax/20,19*m.xmax/20,12):
        lon, lat = m(x,y,inverse=True)
        poly = m.tissot(lon,lat,1.5,100,\
                        facecolor='green',zorder=10,alpha=0.5)
plt.title("Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area Projection")
plt.show()
```

I run it by calling it from the Anaconda prompt in the "basemap" environment, and it works:
[image]

Now I run the same script from Visual Studio Code, in the same environment, and it fails to import:
[image]

What could the problem be? Anything else I should check apart from the environment?

Comment: What is the version of the module "pyproj" you are using? According to the code you provided, I can run it in VSCode, and the version of "pyproj" I used is 1.9.6.

Comment: The version in the `pip list` command is: pyproj==2.6.1.post1

Comment: I tried to use "pyproj==2.6.1.post1", it can also run. What are the version numbers of the modules "matplotlib" and "basemap" you are using? The version number of the module "matplotlib" I use is 3.1.0, and the basemap is 1.2.0. In addition, it is recommended that you try to reinstall the module "basemap" in the current conda environment.

Comment: I tried to make a new environment with your configuration, now the import failure is another: `File "C:...\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    import _geoslib
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`. This in VS Code. When I try to run it by calling from the Anaconda prompt, again it works. I don't understand what's wrong with my Visual Studio...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the console information you provided, the reason is that the terminal console does not enter the conda environment. You can use the following two methods to solve it:

1. Use other terminal consoles in VSCode. "`Ctrl+Shift+p`","`Terminal:Select Default Shell`","`Command Prompt`", open a new terminal console, it will automatically activate and enter the conda environment.

   [image]
2. Use the command "`conda init powershell`" on the console to initialize conda.

   Reopen the powershell console (shortcut key: Ctrl+Shift+`), the powershell will automatically activate and enter the conda environment.

   [image]

Note:

1. when I use method 2, the powershell console shows another error: "`pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] KeyError:'PROJ_LIB'`". The way I fix it is: Use "`conda install -c conda-forge proj4`" to install proj4.
2. When encountering

> ```
> from matplotlib.cbook import dedent
> ImportError: cannot import name 'dedent' from 'matplotlib.cbook' (D:\Users\...\Anaconda3\envs\basemap\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py)
> ```

, which means "`matplotlib` "The version is not compatible, please use "`conda install matplotlib==3.1`" to install version 3.1.

Reference: [conda in powershell](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8428) and [KeyError 'PROJ_LIB](https://github.com/conda-forge/basemap-feedstock/issues/30#issuecomment-425190627).

Comment: I had to do also `conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib-base==3.1`.
Thanks, the cmd prompt in VS Code solved it.